# the function is not alerting something

Tags: javascript, date, alert

using this code to check if the user is over 18 years age or not. but the function is alerting only "you are not 18+". also there is no error in console

for ex:- 23/12/1500        23/12/2008

```
var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value; 
var jsdate = new Date(dob);
var jsdatearray = jsdate.toString().split("/");
var day = jsdatearray[0];
var month = jsdatearray[1];
var year = jsdatearray[2];

var nowdate = new Date();   
nowdate.setFullYear(year, month - 1, day);

var maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setYear(maxDate.getYear() - 18);

if (maxDate < nowdate) {
    alert('you are 18+');
}
else {
    alert('you are not 18+');
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `document.getElementById("dob").value;` ?

Comment: The DOM needs to be fully loaded before calling the said function, is it?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas sorry but it is always alerting your are not 18+

Comment: @Vivick sorry but it is always alerting your are not 18+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things off in the code. First, the date wasn't correctly imported into the Javascript. Second, the condition checking the date was backward. The code below should work better.

```
var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value; 
var jsdatearray = dob.split("-");
var year = jsdatearray[0];
var day = jsdatearray[1];
var month = jsdatearray[2];

var nowdate = new Date();   
nowdate.setFullYear(year, month - 1, day);

var maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setYear(maxDate.getYear() - 18);
console.log(maxDate < nowdate);

if (maxDate > nowdate) {
    alert('you are 18+');
}
else {
    alert('you are not 18+');
}
```